# Using Rrsync with Synology Active Backup for Business - is it save to comment out a line

Tags: linux, ubuntu, backup, rsync

Background: I want to use a Synology diskstation for the backup of Ubuntu Linux servers, without the diskstation having write access to the server for security reasons.

I am using the /usr/bin/rrsync script which is installed on Ubuntu 20.04 to limit access from my Synology DiskStation's Active Backup for business.

To make it work I had to tweak the rrsync script:

I changed the line

```
our $short_disabled = '';
```

(removed "s")

And I commented

```
#die "$0: invalid rsync-command syntax or options\n" if $in_options;
```

In the .ssh/authorized_keys of my backup user I use

```
command="logger \"$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND\"; sudo /usr/bin/rrsync -ro /" ssh-rsa
```

The logger call is for debugging.

When I try to verify the connection in Active Backup for business, the following call is made:

```
rsync --server --sender -sXe.LsfxC
```

This is interpreted as invalid rsync-command syntax or options.

**Question:** Is it save to make those changes to the script or am I undermining the purpose of the restricted rsync script and thus allow the Synology backup server (if it might get compromised) to delete files from the original server?

For reference, the full resulting script I use is:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# Name: /usr/local/bin/rrsync (should also have a symlink in /usr/bin)
# Purpose: Restricts rsync to subdirectory declared in .ssh/authorized_keys
# Author: Joe Smith <js-cgi@inwap.com> 30-Sep-2004
# Modified by: Wayne Davison <wayned@samba.org>
use strict;

use Socket;
use Cwd 'abs_path';
use File::Glob ':glob';

# You may configure these values to your liking.  See also the section
# of options if you want to disable any options that rsync accepts.
use constant RSYNC => '/usr/bin/rsync';
use constant LOGFILE => '/var/log/rrsync.log';

my $Usage = <<EOM;
Use 'command="$0 [-ro|-wo] SUBDIR"'
    in front of lines in $ENV{HOME}/.ssh/authorized_keys
EOM

# Handle the -ro and -wo options.
our $only = '';
while (@ARGV && $ARGV[0] =~ /^-([rw])o$/) {
    my $r_or_w = $1;
    if ($only && $only ne $r_or_w) {
    die "$0: the -ro and -wo options conflict.\n";
    }
    $only = $r_or_w;
    shift;
}

our $subdir = shift;
die "$0: No subdirectory specified\n$Usage" unless defined $subdir;
$subdir = abs_path($subdir);
die "$0: Restricted directory does not exist!\n" if $subdir ne '/' && !-d $subdir;

# The client uses "rsync -av -e ssh src/ server:dir/", and sshd on the server
# executes this program when .ssh/authorized_keys has 'command="..."'.
# For example:
# command="rrsync logs/client" ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAIEAzGhEeNlPr...
# command="rrsync -ro results" ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAIEAmkHG1WCjC...
#
# Format of the environment variables set by sshd:
# SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND=rsync --server          -vlogDtpr --partial . ARG # push
# SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND=rsync --server --sender -vlogDtpr --partial . ARGS # pull
# SSH_CONNECTION=client_addr client_port server_port

my $command = $ENV{SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND};
die "$0: Not invoked via sshd\n$Usage"  unless defined $command;
die "$0: SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND='$command' is not rsync\n" unless $command =~ s/^rsync\s+//;
die "$0: --server option is not first\n" unless $command =~ /^--server\s/;
our $am_sender = $command =~ /^--server\s+--sender\s/; # Restrictive on purpose!
die "$0 sending to read-only server not allowed\n" if $only eq 'r' && !$am_sender;
die "$0 reading from write-only server not allowed\n" if $only eq 'w' && $am_sender;

### START of options data produced by the cull_options script. ###

# These options are the only options that rsync might send to the server,
# and only in the option format that the stock rsync produces.

# To disable a short-named option, add its letter to this string:
our $short_disabled = '';

our $short_no_arg = 'ACDEHIJKLORSWXbcdgklmnoprstuvxyz'; # DO NOT REMOVE ANY
our $short_with_num = 'B'; # DO NOT REMOVE ANY

# To disable a long-named option, change its value to a -1.  The values mean:
# 0 = the option has no arg; 1 = the arg doesn't need any checking; 2 = only
# check the arg when receiving; and 3 = always check the arg.
our %long_opt = (
  'append' => 0,
  'backup-dir' => 2,
  'block-size' => 1,
  'bwlimit' => 1,
  'checksum-seed' => 1,
  'compare-dest' => 2,
  'compress-level' => 1,
  'copy-dest' => 2,
  'copy-unsafe-links' => 0,
  'daemon' => -1,
  'debug' => 1,
  'delay-updates' => 0,
  'delete' => 0,
  'delete-after' => 0,
  'delete-before' => 0,
  'delete-delay' => 0,
  'delete-during' => 0,
  'delete-excluded' => 0,
  'delete-missing-args' => 0,
  'existing' => 0,
  'fake-super' => 0,
  'files-from' => 3,
  'force' => 0,
  'from0' => 0,
  'fuzzy' => 0,
  'group' => 0,
  'groupmap' => 1,
  'hard-links' => 0,
  'iconv' => 1,
  'ignore-errors' => 0,
  'ignore-existing' => 0,
  'ignore-missing-args' => 0,
  'ignore-times' => 0,
  'info' => 1,
  'inplace' => 0,
  'link-dest' => 2,
  'links' => 0,
  'list-only' => 0,
  'log-file' => 3,
  'log-format' => 1,
  'max-delete' => 1,
  'max-size' => 1,
  'min-size' => 1,
  'modify-window' => 1,
  'new-compress' => 0,
  'no-implied-dirs' => 0,
  'no-r' => 0,
  'no-relative' => 0,
  'no-specials' => 0,
  'numeric-ids' => 0,
  'one-file-system' => 0,
  'only-write-batch' => 1,
  'owner' => 0,
  'partial' => 0,
  'partial-dir' => 2,
  'perms' => 0,
  'preallocate' => 0,
  'recursive' => 0,
  'remove-sent-files' => $only eq 'r' ? -1 : 0,
  'remove-source-files' => $only eq 'r' ? -1 : 0,
  'safe-links' => 0,
  'sender' => 0,
  'server' => 0,
  'size-only' => 0,
  'skip-compress' => 1,
  'specials' => 0,
  'stats' => 0,
  'suffix' => 1,
  'super' => 0,
  'temp-dir' => 2,
  'timeout' => 1,
  'times' => 0,
  'use-qsort' => 0,
  'usermap' => 1,
);

### END of options data produced by the cull_options script. ###

if ($short_disabled ne '') {
    $short_no_arg =~ s/[$short_disabled]//go;
    $short_with_num =~ s/[$short_disabled]//go;
}
$short_no_arg = "[$short_no_arg]" if length($short_no_arg) > 1;
$short_with_num = "[$short_with_num]" if length($short_with_num) > 1;

my $write_log = -f LOGFILE && open(LOG, '>>', LOGFILE);

chdir($subdir) or die "$0: Unable to chdir to restricted dir: $!\n";

my(@opts, @args);
my $in_options = 1;
my $last_opt = '';
my $check_type;
while ($command =~ /((?:[^\s\\]+|\\.[^\s\\]*)+)/g) {
  $_ = $1;
  if ($check_type) {
    push(@opts, check_arg($last_opt, $_, $check_type));
    $check_type = 0;
  } elsif ($in_options) {
    push(@opts, $_);
    if ($_ eq '.') {
      $in_options = 0;
    } else {
      die "$0: invalid option: '-'\n" if $_ eq '-';
      next if /^-$short_no_arg*(e\d*\.\w*)?$/o || /^-$short_with_num\d+$/o;

      my($opt,$arg) = /^--([^=]+)(?:=(.*))?$/;
      my $disabled;
      if (defined $opt) {
    my $ct = $long_opt{$opt};
    last unless defined $ct;
    next if $ct == 0;
    if ($ct > 0) {
      if (!defined $arg) {
        $check_type = $ct;
        $last_opt = $opt;
        next;
      }
      $arg = check_arg($opt, $arg, $ct);
      $opts[-1] =~ s/=.*/=$arg/;
      next;
    }
    $disabled = 1;
    $opt = "--$opt";
      } elsif ($short_disabled ne '') {
    $disabled = /^-$short_no_arg*([$short_disabled])/o;
    $opt = "-$1";
      }

      last unless $disabled; # Generate generic failure
      die "$0: option $opt has been disabled on this server.\n";
    }
  } else {
    if ($subdir ne '/') {
      # Validate args to ensure they don't try to leave our restricted dir.
      s{//+}{/}g;
      s{^/}{};
      s{^$}{.};
      die "$0: do not use .. in any path!\n" if m{(^|/)\\?\.\\?\.(\\?/|$)};
    }
    push(@args, bsd_glob($_, GLOB_LIMIT|GLOB_NOCHECK|GLOB_BRACE|GLOB_QUOTE));
  }
}
#die "$0: invalid rsync-command syntax or options\n" if $in_options;

@args = ( '.' ) if !@args;

if ($write_log) {
  my ($mm,$hh) = (localtime)[1,2];
  my $host = $ENV{SSH_CONNECTION} || 'unknown';
  $host =~ s/ .*//; # Keep only the client's IP addr
  $host =~ s/^::ffff://;
  $host = gethostbyaddr(inet_aton($host),AF_INET) || $host;
  printf LOG "%02d:%02d %-13s [%s]\n", $hh, $mm, $host, "@opts @args";
  close LOG;
}

# Note: This assumes that the rsync protocol will not be maliciously hijacked.
exec(RSYNC, @opts, @args) or die "exec(rsync @opts @args) failed: $? $!";

sub check_arg
{
  my($opt, $arg, $type) = @_;
  $arg =~ s/\\(.)/$1/g;
  if ($subdir ne '/' && ($type == 3 || ($type == 2 && !$am_sender))) {
    $arg =~ s{//}{/}g;
    die "Do not use .. in --$opt; anchor the path at the root of your restricted dir.\n"
      if $arg =~ m{(^|/)\.\.(/|$)};
    $arg =~ s{^/}{$subdir/};
  }
  $arg;
}
```